# Change screen to MainScreen after a countdown(inactivity) in kivy MDApp

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I have an App with 3 screens managed by a ScreenManager: MainScreen, ScanScreen, PinScreen. From MainScreen I have 2 buttons, 1 to go to ScanScreen, 1 to go to PinScreen. In ScanScreen I have a button to go into PinScreen and in PinScreen I have a button to go in ScanScreen. I want to go to MainScreen after some interval of time. I managed to make it works only if I go to secondary screens from MainScreen. If I go from MainScreen to ScanScreen and from ScanScreen to PinScreen then it wont work. I get this error:

```
line 16, in timeout
     self.parent.current = 'mainScreen'
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'current'
```

This is what I got so far:

## kv file

```
ScreenManagement:
    id:'screenManager'
    MainScreen:
    ScanScreen:
    PinScreen:
    FinalScreen:


<MainScreen>:
    name: "mainScreen"

    MDCard:
        radius: [36, ]
        size_hint: .8, .9
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
        elevation: 10
        padding: [20, 50, 20, 150]
        spacing: 50
        orientation: 'vertical'

        MDIcon:
            icon: "face-recognition"
            font_size: 120
            halign: 'center'
            size_hint: 1, .5

        MDFillRoundFlatButton:
            text: "Scan Face"
            font_size: 32
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}
            #size_hint: 1, .25
            on_release: 
                root.manager.current = 'scanScreen'
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'

        MDFillRoundFlatButton:
            text: "Access with PIN"
            font_size: 32
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}
            #size_hint: 1, .25
            on_release: 
                root.manager.current = 'pinScreen'
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'

<ScanScreen>:  
    on_pre_enter: app.title = 'Scan Screen'
    name: "scanScreen"
    #on_enter: TODO timer function
    
    MDCard:
        radius: [36, ]
        size_hint: .9, .95
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
        elevation: 10
        padding: [20, 50, 20, 150]
        spacing: 50
        orientation: 'vertical'

        Image:
            id: "frame_feed"
            size_hint: 1, .8

        MDFillRoundFlatButton:
            text: "Access with PIN"
            font_size: 32
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}
            on_release: 
                root.manager.current = 'pinScreen'
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'

<PinScreen>:
    on_pre_enter: app.title = 'PIN Screen'
    name: "pinScreen"

    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        MDBoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            size_hint: (1, .5)

            MDIconButton:
                icon: "arrow-left-drop-circle"
                #icon_size: '32sp' this should be the right way but its not working
                user_font_size: '32sp' #this should be deprecated but it's working
                on_release: 
                    root.manager.current = 'scanScreen'
                    root.manager.transition.direction = 'right'

            MDIcon:
                icon: "account-lock"
                font_size: 60
                halign: 'center'

            MDLabel:
                text: "Enter your passcode"
                halign: "center"
                font_style: "Body1"

            MDGridLayout:
                size_hint: (.5, 1)
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .5}
                cols: 6
                #padding: [80,0,80,0]
                #halign: "center"

                MDIcon:
                    icon:"checkbox-blank-circle-outline"

                MDIcon:
                    icon:"checkbox-blank-circle-outline"

                MDIcon:
                    icon:"checkbox-blank-circle-outline"

                MDIcon:
                    icon:"checkbox-blank-circle-outline"

                MDIcon:
                    icon:"checkbox-blank-circle-outline"

                MDIcon:
                    icon:"checkbox-blank-circle-outline"
                
            Widget:
                size_hint_y: None
                height: 100

        MDBoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            size_hint: (1, .5)

            MDGridLayout:
                size_hint: (.5, 1)
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .385}
                cols:3
                spacing: 20

                MDFillRoundFlatButton:
                    text: "1"
                    text_color: .95,.953,.956,1
                    font_size: 20
                    font_style: 'H4'
                    md_bg_color: .4, .4, .4, 1

                MDFillRoundFlatButton:
                    text: "2"
                    text_color: .95,.953,.956,1
                    font_size: 20
                    font_style: 'H4'
                    md_bg_color: .4, .4, .4, 1

                MDFillRoundFlatButton:
                    text: "3"
                    text_color: .95,.953,.956,1
                    font_size: 20
                    font_style: 'H4'
                    md_bg_color: .4, .4, .4, 1

                MDFillRoundFlatButton:
                    text: "4"
                    text_color: .95,.953,.956,1
                    font_size: 20
                    font_style: 'H4'
                    md_bg_color: .4, .4, .4, 1

                MDFillRoundFlatButton:
                    text: "5"
                    text_color: .95,.953,.956,1
                    font_size: 20
                    font_style: 'H4'
                    md_bg_color: .4, .4, .4, 1

                MDFillRoundFlatButton:
                    text: "6"
                    text_color: .95,.953,.956,1
                    font_size: 20
                    font_style: 'H4'
                    md_bg_color: .4, .4, .4, 1

                MDFillRoundFlatButton:
                    text: "7"
                    text_color: .95,.953,.956,1
                    font_size: 20
                    font_style: 'H4'
                    md_bg_color: .4, .4, .4, 1

                MDFillRoundFlatButton:
                    text: "8"
                    text_color: .95,.953,.956,1
                    font_size: 20
                    font_style: 'H4'
                    md_bg_color: .4, .4, .4, 1

                MDFillRoundFlatButton:
                    text: "9"
                    text_color: .95,.953,.956,1
                    font_size: 20
                    font_style: 'H4'
                    md_bg_color: .4, .4, .4, 1

                MDFillRoundFlatButton:
                    text: ""
                    md_bg_color: 1,0,0,0

                MDFillRoundFlatButton:
                    text: "0"
                    text_color: .95,.953,.956,1
                    font_size: 20
                    font_style: 'H4'
                    md_bg_color: .4, .4, .4, 1

                MDFillRoundFlatIconButton:
                    icon: "backspace"
                    padding: [40,0,0,0]
                    font_style: 'H4'
                    icon_color: .827,.827,.827,1
                    md_bg_color: 1,0,0,0

<FinalScreen>:
    on_pre_enter: app.title = 'Final Screen'
    name: "finalScreen"
```

## python file

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.clock import Clock
Window.size = (414, 736) #This is the viewport of iPhone 6 Plus/6S Plus/7 Plus/8 Plus

import cv2


class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass

class ScanScreen(Screen):
    def timeout(self, *args):
        self.parent.current = 'mainScreen'
    
    def on_enter(self, *args):
        Clock.schedule_once(self.timeout, 2)

class PinScreen(Screen):
    def timeout(self, *args):
        self.parent.current = 'mainScreen'
    
    def on_enter(self, *args):
        Clock.schedule_once(self.timeout, 2)

class FinalScreen(Screen):
    def timeout(self, *args):
        self.parent.current = 'mainScreen'
    
    def on_enter(self, *args):
        Clock.schedule_once(self.timeout, 2)

class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass


class MainApp(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.title = "Main Screen"
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Green"
        self.theme_cls.accent_palette = "Teal"
        return Builder.load_file('main.kv')

    def return_to_main_screen(self):
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

I also tried this:

```
class ScanScreen(Screen):
    def timeout(self, *args):
        MDApp.get_running_app().root.manager.current = 'mainScreen'
        #self.parent.current = 'mainScreen'
    
    def on_enter(self, *args):
        Clock.schedule_once(self.timeout, 2)
```

but I get this error:

```
MDApp.get_running_app().root.manager.current = 'mainScreen'
 AttributeError: 'ScreenManagement' object has no attribute 'manager'
```

Comment: I also tried this: `class ScanScreen(Screen):
    def timeout(self, *args):
        MDApp.get_running_app().root.manager.current = 'mainScreen'
        #self.parent.current = 'mainScreen'
    
    def on_enter(self, *args):
        Clock.schedule_once(self.timeout, 2)` but I get this error `MDApp.get_running_app().root.manager.current = 'mainScreen'
 AttributeError: 'ScreenManagement' object has no attribute 'manager'`

Comment: The `root` of your `App` does not have a `manager` field because it is the manager. Try just leaving off the `manager` part: `MDApp.get_running_app().root.current = 'mainScreen'`

Comment: I had realized that and managed to do what I needed but forgot to update this post. Thanks for your time to answer me anyway

Answer (score 0):

So to clarify, I managed to do what I wanted by using get_running_app() method and accessing the root, which in my case is the ScreenManager. I made some changes to my code so it would reset the countdown after activity. This is what I have in each of the screen that I want to return to MainScreen after 30s of inactivity:

```
class ScanScreen(Screen):
    def timeout(self, *args):
        MDApp.get_running_app().root.current = 'mainScreen'
        MDApp.get_running_app().root.transition.direction = 'right'

    def reset_timeout(self, *args):
        Clock.unschedule(self.timeout)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.timeout, 30)
    
    def on_enter(self, *args):
        Clock.schedule_once(self.timeout, 30)

    def on_leave(self, *args):
        Clock.unschedule(self.timeout)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        self.reset_timeout()
        return super().on_touch_down(touch)
    
    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        self.reset_timeout()
        return super().on_touch_move(touch)
```